# How to proof $\sum_{k=1}^n k {n \choose k }=n 2^{n-1}$

Tags: numerical-methods, combinatorial-proofs

I have tried trying to find a pattern but i don't believe that the right way.
If you help me it would be great.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me correct it

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. Do you know about "combinatorial proofs"? I.e. counting the same set of objects in two different ways, which establishes a formula?

Comment: Actually, I do not know any book of the topic, if you have one it would be great. I'm a pioneer in this proofs.

Comment: What I wrote is the only information they gave me.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your problem, but the following reference may be useful: http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_comb-proofs.html it shows how to prove identities similar to this one. The technique described there should be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the binomial formula states that $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k} $$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ yields $$n(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}y^{n-k}$$

Then taking $x=y=1$, the result follows.